# Carrierwave image dimension validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, validation

I've been reading this post.
[Validate image size in carrierwave uploader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527887/validate-image-size-in-carrierwave-uploader)

It looks like my validator is working correctly, but, I don't get the alert notice. I just get redirected to the form again.

How can I add a rails alert notice to this? Thanks !

```
def validate_minimum_image_size
  image = MiniMagick::Image.open(photo.path)
  unless image[:width] > 400 && image[:height] > 400
  errors.add :image, alert: "should be 400x400px minimum!" 
end
```

Photos controller create method:

```
def create
    @photo = Photo.new(photo_params)
    @photo.user = current_user

    if @photo.save
        redirect_to [current_user, @photo], notice: 'El spot se ha subido correctamente!'
    else
        puts 'shit!!!!!!'
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

Comment: Try removing the `alert` keyword and just give "should be 400x400px minimum!"

Comment: It doesn't work...I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok fixed, I changed

`errors.add :image, alert: "should be 400x400px minimum!"`

to

`errors.add :photo, alert: "should be 400x400px minimum!"`