# CarrierWave validate content type before processing a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I've tried everything now and I can't seem to figure out how to add content type validations in CarrierWave before performing actual processing on files I am uploading. The reason for this is that I want to allow only images but a user can upload a spoofed content file and rename `file.pdf` file to `file.jpg`. Steps I have tried so far:

`photo_uploader.rb`

```
def content_type_whitelist
    /image\//
end
```

I have tried `validate_integrity` in my uploader but no luck as well.
I have also tried overwriting CarrierWave error messages (which seems to me strange to me actually):

```
en:
  errors:
    messages:
      content_type_whitelist: "You are not allowed to upload %{content_type} file"
```

but I am getting an error from MiniMagic

`"Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: %{e}"`

The thing is that I want to display `rails` validations instead so that when the content type is not one of those I have defined in my model it displays the message like `"File should be one of image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif"`. So I need a way to force rails validations to trigger before image processing, although I think it is not quite possible.

[Here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/uploader/magic_mime_whitelist.rb#L14) they say that `CarrierWave::Uploader::MagicMimeWhitelist` should be included in order to perform mime types validations so I've tried that but got `uninitialzied constant CarrierWave::Uploader::MagicMimeWhitelist` (server restarted before)

```
include CarrierWave::Uploader::MagicMimeWhitelist
  def whitelist_mime_type_pattern
    /image\//
  end
```

I've tried using [carrier-mimetype-fu](https://github.com/deviantech/carrierwave-mimetype-fu) but after including `CarrierWave::MimetypeFu` I got `unitilzied constant CarrierWave::MimetypeFu`

Do you have any experience with it?

Comment: Just throwing off some random ideas, have you required the file before including it? Usually, uninitialized constant errors happen in a file cannot be found or not included before being used.

Comment: In rails it is required automagically by default :) Anyway, I've just tried more in-depth debugging and here is what I've found. Carrierwave changes the content type probably based off of file extension. `file -I this_is_pdf.jpg => text/plain` `uploader = PhotoUploader.new.cache!("this_is_pdf.jpg")` `uploader.file.content_type => image/jpg`

Answer (score 4):

I'm answering this two year old question. CarrierWave content type whitelisting relying just on file extension. I tried changing an SWF file's extension to JPG and got a lengthy error direct on UI:

*Validation failed: Photograph Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: 'convert /home/../projects/rails/../tmp/1588146379-380224569365897-0005-2916/android-916817f.png
-auto-orient -resize 170x200^ -sharpen 0x1 -gravity Center -background rgba(255,255,255,0.0) -extent 170x200 /tmp/image_processing20200429-20696-ek1vs1.png` failed with error:*

Spend whole night searching for the solution but got too little on this topic. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10870071/1114817) and [this wiki](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Process-original-image) helped me.

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :file

  before :process, :validate

  process resize_to_fill: [170, 200], convert: :jpg
  .
  .
  def validate(file)
    begin
      image = MiniMagick::Image.open(file.path)
    rescue
      raise "Image format isn't valid"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer

You should be using

```
  def content_type_allowlist
    /image\//
  end
```

This is at least what the [documentation](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#securing-uploads) says.  This question was asked a while ago, so the documentation could've reflected something quite different back then, not sure.  I suppose it only matters what to do now.

In the application that I'm running: when attempting to upload a zip file, where my `content_type_allowlist` only allows image content types, I get an error with the model.

Which is expected, I should only be allowed image types.

#### Code

`task_attached_files.rb`

```
class TaskAttachedFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :task_id, :file
  mount_uploader :file, FileUploader
end
```

`file_uploader.rb`

```
class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::Compatibility::Paperclip
  storage :fog

  def paperclip_path
    "shared/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:basename"
  end

  def content_type_allowlist
    /image\//
  end
end
```